# what are the android libraries for association rule mining?

Tags: android, associations, rule, apriori, mining

I am new to data mining and confused about Association rules libraries for Android. I've found some comments about SPMF and Weka.

Which libraries can be used for Apriori algorithm and association rule mining in android coding using android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use all Java-based source on Android platform. For instance, check [this](https://gist.github.com/monperrus/7157717) link.